# Using pika connection.close() gives "WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0"

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, ipython, jupyter-notebook, pika

When closing a connection to RabbitMQ server using pika, the warning `WARNING:pika.adapters.base_connection:Unknown state on disconnect: 0` appears.

If no `connection.close()` is used, the warning does not appear. What is causing this warning, and is this something we can ignore?

Using Python 2.7, RabbitMQ 3.2.2, iPython 1.1.0, pika 0.9.13 on Mac OSX.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed with pull request [#346](https://github.com/pika/pika/pull/346). Just wait for a new version :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me in RabbitMQ 3.3.3 if I close my BlockingConnection before the channel is completely closed. The solution is to close your connection in the close-callback of the channel. Also, use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) to automatically close the channel.

```
params = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=self._host, port=self._port)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)
with contextlib.closing(connection.channel()) as channel:
    # Close connection once channel is closed
    def closeConnection(channel, replyCode, replyText):
        connection.close()
    channel.add_on_close_callback(closeConnection)

    # Declare a durable queue; we will use the default exchange for
    # simple key-based routing
    channel.queue_declare(queue=self._queueName, durable=True) 
    ...
    ...
```